# I need to spread an increasing large amount of tasks over a few servers, do I spin up VPSes and add keep adding more? Something more scaleable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, architecture, webserver

I need to do a bunch of HTTP requests and then a bunch of processing of the resulting data. It gets quite intensive, to the point that I can't reliably do it on one server anymore, so I created two more Linode VPS in addition to the main one to spread the work load over.

The work is basically the main server sends a bunch of commands to the other servers to do, which includes an HTTP request and what to do with the results, then the other servers perform the fetches, manipulate the data then store it in a central database.

This is working now but the work load is increasing and I'll need to spin up another VPS soon, and the configuration is kind of annoying.

Is there a better way to do this? An automated way to create more servers as needed that isn't super hard to understand? Creating new VPSes is easy just time consuming.

Comment: The question seems to have very little to do with either Go or AWS. Maybe the tags should not be there.

Comment: @MadWombat I agree. The OP doesn't state that he uses these technologies in the post. I think if he does ask if there, for example, solutions in AWS that solve his problem, the tags are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your http requests and processing time is kept to a minimum (less than 15 minutes) [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) is a great option. There is ZERO infrastructure/autoscaling configuration needed, and it is extremely simple to get code up and running. You simply need to upload your code in one of a variety of languages, then add a trigger that kicks off your function.

Another option is to use [AWS Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/) to distribute jobs over a scalable number of instances. You would populate the Batch Job Queue with the requests that you wish for your instances to make. Batch then runs a "job" by passing in a run command to a container that runs on an auto-scaled number of instances based on your job definition.

Setting up a batch environment requires very minimal configuration (setting max/min config values for cpu, mem, etc.), but it does require that your application is stored in ECR as a docker image. Once your batch environment is properly setup, there is very little configuration and maintenance needed.

Answer (score 2):

In AWS you can decouple the workload by using an SQS queue. This in itself might not seem very useful, but you can also create an EC2 auto-scaling group, which scales according to the increase or decrease in messages waiting in the SQS queue. This would allow you to spin up more EC2 instances as needed, but also terminate them when they are not, to reduce costs. For more information, you could have a look here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-using-sqs-queue.html

Comment: So SQS lets me do small one-off tasks repeatedly? How does that differ from Lambda?

Comment: SQS cannot perform any task. It is a message queue for which you can either configure a lambda as a consumer or use something else (e.g., EC2 ) as a consumer. If you need to scale horizontally, you can use lambda, which scales automatically, or configure cloudwatch events to use an auto-scaling group. So the SQS in combination with lambda or an auto scaling group, prevents you from having to boot up extra instances manually.